# Python: Run a code after return something

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is an ApiView from my django project:

```
class Receive_Payment(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    def get(self, request, cc_number):
        if Card.objects.filter(cc_num = cc_number).exists():
            client = Client.objects.get(client_id = (Card.objects.get(cc_num = cc_number).client))
            if not client.is_busy:
                client.is_busy = True
                client.save()
                resp = "successful"
            else:
                resp = "client_is_busy"
        else:
            resp = "fail"
        return Response({"response": resp})
```

As you see, if `client.is_busy` is not `True`, I'm making it `True` in here. But in this situation, I need to `client.is_busy = False` after 30 seconds. If I do it under `client.save()` code, it delays to response. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using timer objects here.

e.g.

```
import threading
def free_up_client(client):
   client.is_busy = false

timer = Theading.timer(30.0, free_up_client, [client])
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a boolean for determining if the client is busy, use a datetime and if it was set less than 30 seconds ago the client is busy. This then means you don't need to run any code after the request

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta


class Client(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def is_busy(self):
        # Can add a property to maintain the same is_busy boolean attribute
        return (now() - self.last_updated) < timedelta(seconds=30)

    def set_busy(self):
        self.last_updated = now()
        self.save()
```